# "parse" function in Language.Haskell.Exts.Parser?

Tags: haskell, haskell-src-exts

There is a function called parse in the title module.  It has a type signature

```
parse :: String -> ParseResult ast
```

I have been working at it for a while and I can't figure out how to use it.  I'm sure its something obvious but I am just not seeing it.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Language.Haskell.Exts.Parser module handles parsing Haskell source code into an appropriate syntax tree. `parse` is a general function to handle parsing a `String` of Haskell source into an instance of the `Parseable` class. For an `Exp` (a Haskell expression), parse is defined as:

```
instance Parseable Exp where
    parse = parseExp
```

So, to use the `parse` function, just provide a type declaration if one cannot be inferred. For example, to parse the expression "5 + 5":

```
parse "5 + 5" :: ParseResult Exp
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
parseExp "5 + 5"
```

In ghci, they both return:

```
ParseOk (InfixApp (Lit (Int 5)) (QVarOp (UnQual (Symbol "+"))) (Lit (Int 5)))
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this function!